# Array.push() method replacing initial index value instead of appending at end

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to push new object values in array on every button click. Instead of this, it replaces the previous value. I think this problem is related to reference but can't seem to fix it.

```
var tranList = []
var newText, newAmount
const [Amount, setAmount] = useState("")
const [Text, setText] = useState("")
function textHandler(event) {
    newText = event.target.value;
    setText(newText)
}
function amountHandler(event){
    newAmount = event.target.value;
    setAmount(newAmount)
}
function clickHandler(){
    console.clear()
    var pair = {}
    pair["text"] = Text
    pair["amount"] = Amount 
    tranList.push(pair)
    // checking if object is pushed or not.
    tranList.map(item => {
        return console.log("Text: ", item.text, " Amount: ", item.amount)
     })
}
```

Comment: How do you know it replaces the previous value? Why don't you console the `transList`?
Also please post more code.

Comment: @Michael I've console the 'transList' please take a look in the clickHandler function. Also this is most of the code, rest is HTML part/ React DOM part.

Comment: Hi, can you add result obtained with the console please ? And what you expect ? Just to be sure

Comment: @MathKimRobin Hi, please have a look at Nadia's answer, I was looking for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way you declare `tranList`

```
var tranList = []
```

Which means a brand new variable is created on each render. It is not that the value is replaced on click, it is being added to an empty array instead. What you need to do is to keep in the state

```
const [tranList , setTranList ] = useState([])
```

and add new values like

```
setTranList(list => [...list, newItem])
```

P.S. If you try to log `tranList` values immideatell after calling `setTranList` you'll notice it is always one step behind, which is expected behaviour, the updated state will be available in `useEffect` callback or/and on the next render.